# родовід: "по материнській лінії" чи "по мамі"?

Tags: from-english, вибір-слова, розмовна-українська

В українській мені зустрічались такі варіанти розрізнення родичів у родоводі:

- *за материнською/батьківською лінією* (приклади є на сторінках [раз](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9), [два](http://prolviv.com/blog/2017/09/12/10-rechei-iakykh-vy-ne-znaly-pro-ukrainski-kazky/));
- *по мамі/матері/татові/батькові* (приклади є на сторінках [три](https://censor.net.ua/resonance/353303/spvavtor_proektu_kniga_pamyat_storik_yaroslav_tinchenko_2700_cholovk_mayije_tochna_tsifra_zagiblih_na), [чотири](http://yanyshivskyy.org.ua/vidguk/));

Чи є між ними стилістична різниця? Друга форма виглядає коротшою та зручнішою, але побоююсь, що це просторіччя.

Цікавить найточніший аналог англійським *maternal*/*paternal*, але знайдені результати з Українсько-англійського словника 1955 р. (К. Андрусишин, Я. Крет) для [*maternal*](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=maternal&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) та [*paternal*](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=paternal&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) потрібного мені контекстного перекладу не містять.

Answer (score 0):

Обидва способи розрізнення родичів у родоводі - за материнською/батьківською лінією та по мамі/матері/татові/батькові - є правильними та зрозумілими для української мови. Обидва варіанти можна вважати стильними та прийнятними для використання у розмовній та писемній мові.

Щодо англійських термінів, то для розрізнення родичів за материнською лінією використовується термін "matrilineal", а для розрізнення за батьківською лінією - "patrilineal". Також для материнської гілки роду можна використовувати термін "maternal" (як у вас вже було зазначено), а для батьківської гілки - "paternal". Терміни "maternal" та "paternal" використовуються ширше, ніж лише для розрізнення родичів у родоводі, тому можуть мати більш широкий контекст.